# How to convert string to DateTime if the language is NOT English

Tags: php, string

There is a date and time string in the format "2 листопада 2020, 21:00, п’ятниця"
I want to convert it to DateTime.
I tried converting.

```
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'uk_UA');
$t = '2 листопада 2020, 21:00, п’ятниця';
$date = date_create_from_format('j F Y, H:i, l', $t);
```

If the language is English, the date is converted, if Ukrainian does not work. How to set the language for conversion.

Comment: November 2nd, 2020 is not a Friday !!!

Comment: @jspit It doesn't work without Friday either.
  `code`  $t = '2 листопада 2020, 21:00';
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'uk', 'ukr');
    $date = date_create_from_format('j F Y, H:i', $t);`code`

Comment: You should check to see if the ukr locale is even installed: https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-install-locales/

Comment: @Sammitch I tried it, one machine had a different locale 'uk_UA', but the code still doesn't work. It seems to me that date_create_from_format only works for English.

Comment: Check the return value from setLocale(). $retVal = setlocale(LC_ALL, 'uk_UA'); var_dump($retVal);
If the ukr locale is not installed, you will get false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the setLocale settings don't affect the functionality of the DateTime class. This class requires names in English. One simple way to solve the problem is to translate the month names and ignore the day name. If ignore the Day Name an incorrect name as in the example cannot generate an error.

```
$t = '2 листопада 2020, 21:00, п’ятниця';

$trans = [
  'січня' => "January",
  'лютого' => "February",
  'березня' => "March",
  'квітня' => "April",
  'травня' => "May",
  'червня' => "June",
  'липня' => "July",
  'серпня' => "August",
  'вересня' => "September",
  'жовтня' => "October",
  'листопада' => "November",
  'грудня' => "December",
];


$inputEn = strtr($t, $trans);
$date = date_create_from_format('j F Y, H:i, *', $inputEn);

var_dump($date);
//object(DateTime)#1 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2020-11-02 21:00:00.000000" ...
```

This solution works independently of the setlocale settings.

The algorithm shown above is built into a PHP extension called **dt** for the DateTime API. You can find it [here](https://github.com/jspit-de/dt).

Using with this class is very easy:

```
$t = '2 листопада 2020, 21:00, п’ятниця';

$ok = dt::setDefaultLanguage('uk_UA');
$dt = dt::createDtFromFormat('j F Y, H:i, *', $t);

echo $dt; //2020-11-02 21:00:00
```